# List of chapters next to image of book cover

Tags: html, css

I need a little help with formatting. I'm not sure how to go about doing what I want to do. Basically, I have a picture of a book, and to the right of it I want to list the chapters of it.

Right now, my image shows, and the chapter list is beneath it. Should I use a table to do this or some kind of foundation column formatting or is there an easier way in css?

My code:

```html
 <h4>The Lone Star Mind: An American Intellectual History</h4>
<h6>Table of Contents for forthcoming manuscript (The University of Texas Press)</h6>

<img src="http://www.shsu.edu/his_rtc/index_files/image033.jpg" style="height:50%; width: 50%">
<ul>
  <li>Preface</li>
  <li>Introduction: Promise & Peril beyond the Cultural Turn <a href="http://www.shsu.edu/his_rtc/LSM/INTRODUCTION_use_this_one.htm">(Read draft)</a>
  </li>
  <li>Chapter 1. The Lone Star Mind: The Traditional Texas Past in Historical Perspective</li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to use `float: left` to let text wrap around the image. However, this will still allow the chapter list to grow past the height of the image, so if you want to make sure the chapters list doesn't exceed that height, you will need to add a couple containers and use `overflow: auto` somewhere to enable scrolling on the chapter list.

```css
img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<h4>The Lone Star Mind: An American Intellectual History</h4>
<h6>Table of Contents for forthcoming manuscript (The University of Texas Press)</h6>

<img src="http://www.shsu.edu/his_rtc/index_files/image033.jpg" style="height:50%; width: 50%">
<ul>
  <li>Preface</li>
  <li>Introduction: Promise & Peril beyond the Cultural Turn <a href="http://www.shsu.edu/his_rtc/LSM/INTRODUCTION_use_this_one.htm">(Read draft)</a>
  </li>
  <li>Chapter 1. The Lone Star Mind: The Traditional Texas Past in Historical Perspective</li>
```

Here's a demo for the method using containers. I think the most semantically appropriate use of HTML5 tags here would be `figure` and `figcaption`, but someone can correct me if there's a better choice!

```css
.book {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.book img {
  display: block;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
}

.book .contents {
  height: 300px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<h4>The Lone Star Mind: An American Intellectual History</h4>
<h6>Table of Contents for forthcoming manuscript (The University of Texas Press)</h6>

<figure class="book">
  <img class="cover" src="http://www.shsu.edu/his_rtc/index_files/image033.jpg">
  <figcaption class="contents">
    <ul>
      <li>Preface</li>
      <li>Introduction: Promise & Peril beyond the Cultural Turn <a href="http://www.shsu.edu/his_rtc/LSM/INTRODUCTION_use_this_one.htm">(Read draft)</a>
      </li>
      <li>Chapter 1. The Lone Star Mind: The Traditional Texas Past in Historical Perspective</li>
      <li>Some more chapters to test.</li>
      <li>Some more chapters to test.</li>
      <li>Some more chapters to test.</li>
      <li>Some more chapters to test.</li>
      <li>Some more chapters to test.</li>
      <li>Some more chapters to test.</li>
      <li>Some more chapters to test.</li>
      <li>Some more chapters to test.</li>
      <li>Some more chapters to test.</li>
      <li>Some more chapters to test.</li>
      <li>Some more chapters to test.</li>
      <li>Some more chapters to test.</li>
      <li>Some more chapters to test.</li>
      <li>Some more chapters to test.</li>
      <li>Some more chapters to test.</li>
    </ul>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
```